# Firebase Function not being deployed in flutter

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, npm, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy firebase function for flutter application which is being created in android studio. While deploying I am receiving following error. How should I resolve it?

> Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
>
> functions@ lint /Users/johnny/Downloads/flutterApp5/functions
>   eslint .
>
> /Users/johnny/Downloads/flutterApp5/functions/index.js
>   18:5   error    Expected catch() or return
>   promise/catch-or-return   23:13  error    Each then() should return a
>   value or throw  promise/always-return   28:13  error    Expected
>   catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return   28:13 
>   warning  Avoid nesting promises
>   promise/no-nesting   33:21  error    Each then() should return a value
>   or throw  promise/always-return   45:19  warning  Avoid nesting
>   promises                      promise/no-nesting   45:19  warning 
>   Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting   48:27
>   error    Each then() should return a value or throw 
>   promise/always-return
>
> ✖ 8 problems (5 errors, 3 warnings)
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! functions@ lint:
>   `eslint .` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the
>   functions@ lint script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
>   npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/johnny/.npm/_logs/2020-06-14T01_33_52_121Z-debug.log
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero
>   exit code1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a `eslint` error. Check the following error messages.

```
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

functions@ lint /Users/johnny/Downloads/flutterApp5/functions eslint .

/Users/johnny/Downloads/flutterApp5/functions/index.js 18:5 error Expected catch() or return
promise/catch-or-return 23:13 error Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return 28:13 error Expected catch() or return promise/catch-or-return 28:13 warning Avoid nesting promises
promise/no-nesting 33:21 error Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return 45:19 warning Avoid nesting promises promise/no-nesting 45:19 warning Avoid nesting promises promise/no-nesting 48:27 error Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return

✖ 8 problems (5 errors, 3 warnings)
```

You should edit your code to fix error, or change `promise/catch-or-return` and `promise/always-return` rules from `error` to `warn` in your `.eslintrc.json` configuration file.

See https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise

### In addition

`npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint` command is `functions.predeploy` setting in the `firebase.json` file.

Like this.

```
{
...
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
....
}
```